# Lotus Notes 7 - Difference between two days ( excluding the weekend days ) in days

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-formula, difference

I want to determine the number of days between two date/time fields : Start and Stop, but excluding the weekend days.

So if Start = let say some date on Friday and Stop = the next Monday => the difference is TWO

I will appreciate any help

PS : I found this : http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256AFA0078F418

It works! I know asking the admin if I should leave this question opened or just delete-it. Many thanks!

Comment: You think about deleting the question? No, don't do it. Naveen gave you the perfect answer to your question! The solution you found is from "before Notes 6" time. My recommendation: just use `@BusinessDays(startDT;endDT;1:7)` and vote up and accept Naveen's answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [`@BusinessDays`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_BUSINESSDAYS_FUNCTION.html) where you can include days and dates to exclude while finding difference between two dates.